# Correct OpenGL matrix format?

Tags: math, opengl, matrix

My question simply is: what is the correct format for the Projection and ModelView matrix?

I've been told that the following example matrices are transposed and are not built like OpenGL matrices should be.

```
ModelView Matrix
{(1, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0.7071068, 0.7071068, 0)
(0, -0.7071068, 0.7071068, 0)
(0, -141.4214, -141.4214, 1)}

Projection Matrix
{(1.931371, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 2.414213, 0, 0)
(0, 0, -1.0002, -1)
(0, 0, -2.0002, 0)}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Edit: this answer is in serious need of an update. Namely, there is no consideration about shaders.**

**As @gman points out in the comments, whether to use row-major or column-major depends on how you do your math. You may choose one or the other (or even both at different times if you don't think that's confusing) just as long as they match your coordinate systems and order of operations.**

**I'm leaving this answer as community wiki in case someone has the time and will to update it.**

---

OpenGL specifies matrices as a one-dimensional array listed in column-major order, ie with elements ordered like this:

```
m0 m4 m8  m12
m1 m5 m9  m13
m2 m6 m10 m14
m3 m7 m11 m15
```

So if you initialize an array this way, in C or pretty much any other language, the resulting matrix will look like it needs transposing, because C code reads left-to-right first and then top-to-bottom (in other words, like if it were in row-major order):

```
int mat[16] = {
    0, 1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6, 7,
    8, 9, 10, 11,
    12, 13, 14, 15,
}
```

By the way, OpenGL has both [glLoadTransposeMatrix](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glLoadTransposeMatrix.xml) and [glMultTransposeMatrix](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glMultTransposeMatrix.xml), which you can use instead of glLoadMatrix and glMultMatrix, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: So how can I tell if the matrixes from my question are in column- or row-major order?

Comment: The model-view matrix has non-zero elements in the last row, while the last column read (0, 0, 0, 1). This means it is in row-major order. (As per http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html#modelview )

Comment: Meanwhile, contrasting the projection matrix with the one in this link - http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html - it seems it is in column-major order. Please notice I haven't really put much thought into this, though.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. OpenGL definitely supports both row-major and column-major order. If you're using glUniformMatrix4fv, the 3rd argument is true if you are using row-major, false if you are using column-major. Actually, most programming languages that use C-style arrays and syntax would fine row-major to be more convenient.

Comment: @TalLiron Isn't that what I said, that in most programming languages it's easier to initialize a matrix in row-major form? The transposition comes from the way you write in a text editor being different from the way you'd write following the usual math convention. It's not really related to how OpenGL treats the matrices.

Comment: @TalLiron The third argument to `glUniformMatrix4fv` being true doesn't necessarily mean your matrix is row-major. It just means you want to transpose it. You may want to transpose a column-major matrix for some reason. And you're better off with it being false: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15032/why-must-the-transpose-value-of-gluniformmatrix4fv-in-webgl-opengl-es-be-false/15035#15035

Comment: Column major vs Row major is a matter of usage not storage. You can store the data any way you want, it's up to the particular math functions whether the result they generate is considered column major or row major.

Answer (score 6):

You can use whichever notation you like, as long as you're consistent with the ordering of matrix operations. Quoting from https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm:

> **9.005 Are OpenGL matrices column-major or row-major?**
>
> For programming purposes, OpenGL matrices are 16-value arrays with
>   base vectors laid out contiguously in memory. The translation
>   components occupy the 13th, 14th, and 15th elements of the 16-element
>   matrix, where indices are numbered from 1 to 16 as described in
>   section 2.11.2 of the OpenGL 2.1 Specification.
>
> Column-major versus row-major is purely a notational convention. Note
>   that post-multiplying with column-major matrices produces the same
>   result as pre-multiplying with row-major matrices. The OpenGL
>   Specification and the OpenGL Reference Manual both use column-major
>   notation. You can use any notation, as long as it's clearly stated.

i.e. in a shader you can load transformation matrices as float arrays ordered by **columns** into a uniform and **pre-multiply** a vertex to transform it:

```
gl_Position = Proj * View * Model * vPosition;
```

or load the same matrices as float arrays ordered by **rows** and **post-multiply** to achieve the same effect:

```
gl_Position = vPosition * Model * View * Proj;
```

By transposing a matrix you effectively transform it to be stored in the opposite notation, which is why OpenGL has options to transpose matrices as they are inputted.

Comment: This looks backwards. The first order of multiplications is used for column-major matrices, the second for row-major matrices.

Comment: In case anyone is confused by the comment above ("This looks backwards"), the post has already been edited to reflect that comment. Just saying in case it isn't obvious, because this **** is confusing enough as it is. :)