# Why Transform Matrix doesn't work in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

Say I want to draw a Ball in the scene and here are two different ways to do them.

```
float SUN_TRANSLATION_MATRIX[] = {
  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -15.0f,
  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};

void displaySolarSystem1(){
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -15.f);
  glColor3f(1.0f, 0.8f, 0.5f);
  glutSolidSphere(2.0, 50, 40);
  glutSwapBuffers();
}

void displaySolarSystem(){
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();         
  glMultMatrixf(SUN_TRANSLATION_MATRIX);
  glColor3f(1.0f, 0.8f, 0.5f);
  glutSolidSphere(2.0, 50, 40); 
  glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

displaySolarSystem1 applies glTranslatef where displaySolarSystem uses Matrix operation the problem is that displaySolarSystem1 works as expected but the matrix failed.

What went wrong with displaySolarSystem()?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360918/correct-opengl-matrix-format. Basically your matrix is transposed.

Comment: I'm not sure, but i gues that you should simply get the translation information from the matrix, and use glTranslatef to translate it just like in the displaySolarSystem1()

Comment: Not an answer but a debugging hint, use glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW, modelMatrix); to inspect the matrix in the case where it does work then compare to the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glMultMatrix.xml

> Calling glMultMatrix with an argument of m = [...] replaces the current transformation with C × M × v

Which means that transformations are applied by multiplying matrix by vector, not vice versa. So, translation matrix would be something like this
    1 0 0 X
    0 1 0 Y
    0 0 1 Z
    0 0 0 1
But this is matrix, that is written in row-major order, and OpenGL takes column-major order matrices, so you need to transpose it.
So, finally, you just need to use `glMultTransposeMatrix` which, if I remember right, is slightly slower, or transpose your matrix to look like this

```
float SUN_TRANSLATION_MATRIX[] = {
  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
  0.0f, 0.0f, -15.0f, 1.0f
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Unwind. The problem was solved by changing glMultMatrixf(SUN_TRANSLATION_MATRIX); to glMultTransposeMatrixf(SUN_TRANSLATION_MATRIX); thanks for your hint of "this is a transposed matrix"