# WebGL code produces same matrices as pre-made library but does not display the same

Tags: javascript, canvas, matrix, opengl-es, webgl

I am working on a 3D function library (for fun) and am unable to find the error in my code. From what I can see, the matrices produced by my code and a pre-made library are exactly the same. I am using the same vertex positions but nothing is showing and it's driving me crazy.

My Version:
http://robjte.de/webgl/notworking.html
http://jsfiddle.net/uh9574z0/

The pre-made working version (target output):
http://robjte.de/webgl/working.html
http://jsfiddle.net/5daae976/

I have console logged the matrices on each version.

Main segment (my version):

```
var translate = [0.5, 0, 0];
var modelMatrix = identity(4);
modelMatrix.setXY(3, 0, translate[0]);
modelMatrix.setXY(3, 1, translate[1]);
modelMatrix.setXY(3, 2, translate[2]);

var eye = createVector([0, 0, 2.25]);
var focus = createVector([0, 0, 0]);
var up = createVector([0, 1, 0]);

modelMatrix = modelMatrix;
var viewMatrix = lookAt(eye, focus, up);
var projectionMatrix = perspective(canvas, 50 * Math.PI / 180, 1, 10);
```

Main segment (working version):

```
// local coords -> world space
var modelMatrix = mat4.create();
mat4.translate(modelMatrix, modelMatrix, vec3.fromValues(0.5, 0.0, 0.0));

// world space -> camera space
var eye = vec3.fromValues(0, 0, 2.25);
var lookAt = vec3.fromValues(0, 0, 0);
var up = vec3.fromValues(0, 1, 0);
var viewMatrix = mat4.create();

mat4.lookAt(viewMatrix, eye, lookAt, up);

var projMatrix = mat4.create();
mat4.perspective(projMatrix, 50 * Math.PI / 180, canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight, 1, 10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. My arrays were in row major order instead of column major order as required by GLSL. This helped a lot: [Correct OpenGL matrix format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360918/correct-opengl-matrix-format)

Comment: Glad you found your issue. FYI though, column major vs row major is not a matter of storage, it's a matter of how the data is used in your math functions. You can swap the way they are stored AND swap the way they are used in your math functions and you'll get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your math lib is actually generating the same results. I used the [WebGL Inspector](http://benvanik.github.io/WebGL-Inspector/) to look at the state of the program in each of your links. There's a few very significant differences.

[image: not the same]

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the link to that inspector as well, could be very useful.