# OpenGL: How are base vectors laid out in memory

Tags: opengl, matrix

this topic has been discussed quite a few times. There are a lot of information on the memory layout of matrices in OpenGL on the internet. Sadly different sources often contradict each other.

My question boils down to:

> When I have three base vectors of my matrix `bx`, `by` and `bz`. If I want to make a matrix out of them to plug them into a shader, how are they laid out in memory?

**Lets clarify what I mean by base vector, because I suspect this can also mean different things:**

When I have a 3D model, that is Z-up and I want to lay it down flat in my world space along the X-axis, then `bz` is `[1 0 0]`. I.e. a vertex `[0 0 2]` in model space will be transformed to `[2 0 0]` when that vertex is multiplied by my matrix that has `bz` as the base vector for the Z-axis.

**Coming to OpenGL matrix memory layout:**

According to the GLSL spec ([GLSL Spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.50.pdf) p.110) it says:

```
vec3 v, u;
mat3 m;
u = v * m;

is equivalent to

u.x = dot(v, m[0]); // m[0] is the left column of m
u.y = dot(v, m[1]); // dot(a,b) is the inner (dot) product of a and b
u.z = dot(v, m[2]);
```

So, in order to have best performance, I should premultiply my vertices in the vertex shader (that way the GPU can use the dot product and so on):

```
attribute vec4 vertex;
uniform mat4 mvp;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vertex * mvp;
}
```

Now OpenGL is said to be column-major ([GLSL Spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.50.pdf) p 101). I.e. the columns are laid out contiguously in memory:

```
[ column 0 | column 1 | column 2  | column 3    ]
[ 0 1 2 3  | 4 5 6 7  | 8 9 10 11 | 12 13 14 15 ]
```

or:

```
[
    0  4  8 12,
    1  5  9 13,
    2  6 10 14,
    3  7 11 15,
]
```

This would mean that I have to store my base vectors in the rows like this:

```
bx.x bx.y bx.z 0
by.x by.y by.z 0
bz.x bz.y bz.z 0
0    0    0    1
```

So for my example with the 3D model that I want to lay flat down, it has the base vectors:

```
bx = [0 0 -1]
by = [0 1  0]
bz = [1 0  0]
```

The model vertex `[0 0 2]` from above would be transformed like dis in the vertex shader:

```
// m[0] is [ 0 0 1 0]
// m[1] is [ 0 1 0 0]
// m[2] is [-1 0 0 0]
// v    is [ 0 0 2 1]
u.x = dot([ 0 0 2 1], [ 0 0 1 0]);
u.y = dot([ 0 0 2 1], [ 0 1 0 0]);
u.z = dot([ 0 0 2 1], [-1 0 0 0]);
// u    is [ 2 0 0]
```

Just as expected!

**On the contrary:**

This: [Correct OpenGL matrix format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360918/correct-opengl-matrix-format)
SO question and consequently the [OpenGL Faq](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm) states:

> For programming purposes, OpenGL matrices are 16-value arrays with base vectors laid out contiguously in memory. The translation components occupy the 13th, 14th, and 15th elements of the 16-element matrix, where indices are numbered from 1 to 16 as described in section 2.11.2 of the OpenGL 2.1 Specification.

This says that my base vectors should be laid out in columns like this:

```
bx.x by.x bz.x 0
bx.y by.y bz.y 0
bx.z by.z bz.z 0
0    0    0    1
```

To me these two sources which both are official documentation from Khronos seem to contradict each other.

Can somebody explain this to me? Have I made a mistake? Is there indeed some wrong information?

Comment: You can control the CPU memory layout of matrices by setting the transpose parameter of the `glUniformMatrix` commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FAQ is correct, it should be:

```
bx.x by.x bz.x 0
bx.y by.y bz.y 0
bx.z by.z bz.z 0
0    0    0    1
```

and it's your reasoning that is flawed.

Assuming that your base vectors bx, by, bz are the model basis given in world coordinates, then the transformation from the model-space vertex v to the world space vertex Bv is given by linear combination of the base vectors:

```
B*v = bx*v.x + by*v.y + bz*v.z
```

*It is not a dot product of b with v.* Instead it's the matrix multiplication where B is of the above form.

Taking a dot product of a vertex u with bx would answer the inverse question: given a world-space u what would be its coordinates in the model space along the axis bx? Therefore multiplying by the *transposed* matrix `transpose(B)` would give you the transformation from world space to model space.

Comment: Yes it is the matrix multiplication. But that can be implemented on the GPU via dot products. I did not calculate the dot product of a base vector and a vertex but the the vector of all x, of all y and of all z and the vertex. And that should be exactly the linear combination that you described.

Comment: Oh, you multiply the vector from the left, but all the world multiplies the vectors from the right: `gl_Position = mvp * vertex;`. Sure you can transpose everything and get from-the-left multiplications instead.

Comment: The reason I did this, is because the GLSL spec said that the multiplication can be done with dot products and not by adding and multiplying single matrix components. This seemed faster to me as there are GPU instructions for dot products which can then be used.

Comment: @jsf: Then you misinterpreted what you read. The GPU can do right-multiplication just as fast as left-multiplication. Stop prematurely optimizing stuff.

Comment: @jsf: please don't do this. It doesn't matter. AFAIK today's GPU cores are scalar processors, so there's no dot-product instruction in the hardware.

Comment: ok, ok, so I take the the memory layout from the faq and multiply from the right and then I am fine?

Comment: Yes. (Personally I like using quaternions, BTW)

Comment: If I already have a direction vector that I want my model to look at then constructing the base vectors is easier for me.